# Impresspages file uploads mask

Tags: impresspages

Linux server, running suphp with Apache 2.2.22 and PHP5.5.17

When I upload an image using the image widget, it is stored in a date-based path under /file
the path directories are created with properties of `-rwx------`, and the file is stored with properties of `-rw-------`

This works fine when I am traversing the directory using shell, but Apache can't see the files, as it runs as not me.

What is a safe file into which I can add `umask(002);` that will be early enough in the application logic, but won't get overridden by updates? Can I create a Plugin and make it the only thing in the routes.php? Can I put this in my Theme file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such setting in ImpressPages yet. I guess you have to configure your Linux to use the right mask by default. Have you seen such a setting on other CMSs or Frameworks?

Comment: A quick grep of Wordpress shows umask settings. A quick grep of MyGedView shows umask settings. I also see umask settings in Magento. I'm not saying it needs to be added, I need to add it somewhere, and I don't want it to be overwritten by an update.

Comment: Files are being created in many places. It won't be easy to implement such a setting. The fact that Magento has such option makes me think it might be needed to implement.

But I can't find any evidence of that setting in WP https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-and-umask

Comment: Wordpress uses umask when updating. See wp-admin/includes/upgrade and wp-admin/includes/class-ftp.php. I don't see it in file uploads, but I'm not sure if it needs to create date-based directories.

Comment: I just updated one of my WordPress installations, and all the files are now -rw-r--r-- and owned by me and my group. I uploaded an image to post, and WordPress also adjusted the permissions to -rw-r--r-- Maybe it's not necessarily an umask() issue but a chmod() issue.